# Upgrade to react-native 0.16 error

Tags: react-native

I upgraded my app from react-native 0.15 to 0.16 but after that I'm getting an error and I don't know how to solve it.

[image]

```
TypeError:undefined is not an object (evaluating 'GLOBAL.Text={
get defaultProps(){
throw getInvalidGlobalUseError('Text')}}')
```

In Chrome Debugger:

```
Uncaught Error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'Text' of undefined
```

Thanks

**OBS:** I'm running on Android.

I notice that changing app name solves the problem, I'm using Evently as app name today. I tried to recreate my virtual machine but didn't solve it.

Comment: I'm having the same issue on iOS. Looking at the Xcode log, I get a `Requiring unknown module "RCTLog"` message.

Answer (score 10):

In my case, I was able to narrow the cause down to one item in my `.babelrc` file:

```
{
    "presets": ["es2015"]
}
```

As soon as I removed that and restarted the packager (making sure to also use the `--reset-cache` flag), I stopped getting the error.

---

**Update 2:**
It looks like React Native is making some [changes](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/e6cb02d61af82832016bafb259a1b0d3039a357e) to their `.babelrc` in version `0.20.0`.  So, if you are using that version or newer, you should follow the instructions at: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/tree/master/babel-preset in order to specify your `.babelrc` settings.

**Update**:
I've narrowed this down further to `transform-es2015-modules-commonjs`, which React-Native sets some options on, specifically `{"strict": false, "allowTopLevelThis": true}`.  The `es2015` preset does not set this option, and it seems that the React-Native .babelrc does not override it.  If you want to use es6 modules and transform them to commonjs, you'll need to put the following in your .babelrc:

```
{
    "plugins": [
        ["transform-es2015-modules-commonjs", {"strict": false, "allowTopLevelThis": true}]
    ]
}
```

---

Note, Babel 6, which I updated to along with react-native 0.16.0, no longer contains any transforms by default.  What I didn't initially realize is that the React-Native packager provides most of the transforms you might ever need (listed in their docs at: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/javascript-environment.html#javascript-syntax-transformers), and I'm thinking that the "es2015" plugin interferes with some of those transformers.

I also tried using "babel-preset-react" (http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-react/), and that plugin did not seem to cause any errors.

Comment: I removed the "es2015" plugin from my .babelrc, and restarted the packager with --reset-cache, but I now get other errors.

Comment: Sounds like progress. :)

Comment: Yeah yeah. Thanks! ;-)

Comment: Wow, I had no idea RN had its own preset until I read Update 2. TYMK

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem. I think it was because permissions in project folder. I ran chown in my folder to correct the permissions problems and now all are working.

Thanks

Comment: Can you give some more details about what you did to solve the problem?  I'm having similar issues, and I'm not sure what you mean by `ran chown` in your folder.  What exactly did you do?

Comment: What was the chown you ran?

Comment: My problem was about folder permissions. Chown is a command line for mac and linux to change the ownership of the folder. The chown I used looks like that `chown -R user folder` where `-R` is to run recursively.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was a rogue .babelrc two folders up (my root code folder); I had initiated a yeoman generator to scaffold out a new project using babel-6...accidentally running yeoman from the root code folder. Apparently babel traversed upwards from my project folders until it hit this .babelrc which borked the react-native babel configs...

^ this was originally an edit to my initial answer, which was deleted WHILE I WAS UPDATING IT